# Django filter for many to many by multiple

Tags: python, mysql, django

`Author` has the manytomany entity `Article`

I can use filter for manytomany like this

```
a = Author.objects.get(id=1)

Article.objects.filter(authors=a)
```

However I want to filter auther a and auther b

like

```
Article.objects.filter(authors=a and authors=b)
```

How can I make it??

Comment: I think you need an OR: "authors=a or authors=b"?

Comment: Ah yes, I need OR not And

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
# for OR
from django.db.models import Q
Article.objects.filter(Q(authors=a) | Q(authors=b))
```

hope this helps

Comment: Its quite simple and nice solution . thank you very much!!